# Nested Mapped Laravel Query with Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am outputting a query which has a relationship with another model.

One of the fields I need is within the relationship

```
  $officeFlagMap = $officeFlagQuery->map(function ($item) {
     return [
        'propagent_id'   => $propagent_id,
     ];
     $item->theAgent->map(function ($inner){
        return [
           'agtFullName'   => $inner->agtFullName,
        ];
     });
  });
```

I have checked that both values are correct but I am only getting the output for the 
`$inner->agtFullName.`
How can I modify this to chain the returns and show both fields?

Comment: Couple of things I see off hand. $propagent_id isn't declared in that function scope. If you need to pull it in, use the use keyword on the function (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php in example 3). Also were you return $propagent_id, the code after it isn't run with the additional map. I would try reversing those two statements and put in the return after the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an ideal code would be,

```
$officeFlagMap = $officeFlagQuery->map(function ($item) {

  return [
        'propagent_id' => $item->propagent_id, // use the appropriate variable here 
        'agtFullName'  => $item->theAgent->map(function ($inner){
                              return [
                                'agtFullName'   => $inner->agtFullName,
                               ];
                           });
  ];
});
```

this will map over the original collection and again on the `theAgent` collection and will return the result.

Comment: I should edit the original but the real variable is $item->propagent_id

Comment: It looks good, but syntax wise im getting an error with this part - $officeFlagMap = $officeFlagQuery->map(function ($item) {

  return [  -  It doenst like the bracket after the word return... trying to figure it out

Comment: Thank you for the fast help Shobi! that did it